# How to plot filtered data with loop in R and combine them with facet_grid?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggtitle

I am new in R, so my question could seem very trivial for someone, but I need a solution. I have a data frame:

```
`structure(list(Time = c(0, 0, 0), Node = 1:3, Depth = c(0, -10, 
-20), Head = c(-1000, -1000, -1000), Moisture = c(0.166, 0.166, 
0.166), HeadF = c(-1000, -1000, -1000), MoistureF = c(0.004983, 
0.004983, 0.004983), Flux = c(-0.00133, -0.00133, -0.00133), 
    FluxF = c(-0.00122, -0.00122, -0.00122), Sink = c(0, 0, 0
    ), Transf = c(0, 0, 0), TranS = c(0, 0, 0), Temp = c(20, 
    20, 20), ConcF = c(0, 0, 0), ConcM = c(0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")`.
```

I am able to plot a single  TranS vs Time [Single plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuN1h.png), where color = Transf (using scale_color_viridis). I want to create plots with a filtered data for( depth = -20, depth = -40 , -60, -80 and -100) Note: that title also have to be changed according to a depth value. These plots then I want to put next to each other using facet_grid.

I have tried in a such way:

```
plot_d20 <-plot_node %>% filter(plot_node$Depth == -20)
plot_d40 <-plot_node %>% filter(plot_node$Depth == -40)
plot_d60 <-plot_node %>% filter(plot_node$Depth == -60)
plot_d80 <-plot_node %>% filter(plot_node$Depth == -80)
plot_d100 <-plot_node %>% filter(plot_node$Depth == -100)

depth_plot <- c(plot_d20,plot_d40,plot_d60,plot_d80,plot_d100)

for (p in depth_plot){
ggpS<-ggplot(p, aes(Time, TranS, color=Transf) ) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 1)+
  scale_color_viridis(option = "D")+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1400), breaks = seq(0,1400,200))+
  ggtitle('Solute Mass Transfer for depth = 20mm')
ggpS
}
```

But it doesn't work.
R says:
`data` must be a data frame, or another object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector. And I don't know how to make my title dynamic and combine it with facet_grid or on a single plot, but in this case, I will face difficulty to distinguish the lines and assigning the legend to the plot by color, because color already represents another variable. What is the possible way to accomplish that?

Comment: You could use either `grid.arrange()` from the `gridExtra` package or [`plot_grid()`](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) from the `cowplot` package to place figures in a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post to include your data as text, not an image? Run `dput(plot_node)` in R then just paste the result into your post.

Comment: @Muru thanks. See my edited answer using your data.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Understand the question differently.

`facet_grid` accepts a single `data.frame`, and uses one of that frames values to split a chart into multiple subplots. Your question describes combining multiples charts into a single chart, which is available as a function from the `cowplot` library. However, If you are interested in faceting the data, here is a way to `filter` and `facet_wrap`.

Example with Iris data:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length %in% c(6.4,5.7,6.7,5.1,6.3,5)) %>%  ### Your values here
  ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color=Species)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 1) +
  scale_color_viridis_d()+ #(option = "D") + ### New function name
  #scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,1400), breaks = seq(0,1400,200))+
  facet_wrap("Sepal.Length") +
  # facet_grid("Sepal.Length") + ### Alternative Layout
  ggtitle('Sepal Length Range')
```

[image]

Comment: Reimagining the question is an important and useful technique, not just in this example, but more generally.  This answer points this out very clearly and gets a +1 from me because of it.  Often, a pain point is related more to the implementation than the underlying principle and considering other routes to the ultimate objective can both remove the specific pain and provide more general insight.

Answer (score 0):

To create a "grid" of plots with only one faceting variable, you'll actually want to use `facet_wrap()`. You can create your facet titles before plotting, and change the formatting of `strip.text` within `theme()` to make them look more "title-like."

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plot_node %>% 
  mutate(
    facet = paste0("Solute Mass Transfer for Depth = ", abs(Depth), "mm")
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Time, TranS, color=Transf)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 1) +
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "D") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1400), breaks = seq(0, 1400, 200)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(facet), ncol = 2, scales = "free") +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 12, face = "bold"))
```

[image]